# How to execute multiple gnuplot commands in C++/C code

Tags: c++, c, gnuplot

I have two questions. My program is generating data into let's say file.txt. From the level of my program, I would like to call some gnuplot commands.

I can plot data saved in file.txt by calling

```cpp
    system("gnuplot -p -e \"plot 'file.txt'\"");
```

Can anyone explain me what those two extra options do -p -e, without them gnuplot does not start.

But before plotting, I would like for example set the label for x-axis and y-axis.
How can I do it?

This code

```cpp
system("gnuplot -p -e \"set xlabel 'h'\"");
system("gnuplot -p -e \"plot 'file.txt'\"");
```

Does not work, Program ends without errors, but label for x axis is not setted up.

Comment: `-p, --persist lets plot windows survive after main gnuplot program exits.` , 

`-e "command list" executes the requested commands before loading the next input file.` from the [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gnuplot.1.html)

Comment: `gnuplot` has ample documentation for its options and a description for how to use it. If you have further questions, the program's has a very good web site that has plenty of additional documentation. What exactly in gnuplot's documentation is unclear to you?

Comment: Does that work from a cmd command batch file? Your code opens an instance of `gnuplot` every time you call the `system()` function.

Comment: When using cmd, I starting gnuplot, then typing  set xlabel 'h', then plot "output.txt", and everything is fine, the plot is visiable and xlabel is set to "h". But when running a program xlabel is not set to "h".

Comment: @XYZ123 _" then typing set xlabel 'h', then plot "output.txt""_That's definitely not the same as running a separate gnuplot instance everytime.

Comment: Fine, system("gnuplot -p -e  \"set xlabel 'h' ; plot 'output.txt'\"");, works fine thank you @πάνταῥεῖ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One execution of `gnuplot` creates one plot.*

Independent invocations of the program do not modify the same plot. That's the same as if you were typing on the commandline.

Also just as if you were typing on the commandline, you pass `gnuplot` *arguments* to describe the plot you want (per its documentation). That can take the form of a gnuplot "script" given with `-e`, or a script given as a plot file (I forget the argument for that but, again, read the documentation).

gnuplot script format is also well-documented and you can specify multiple commands inside one of those, separated either by newlines or (particularly relevant from the commandline) by semicolons.

<sub>* loosely; I think actually a single invocation can produce multiple results using some combination of commands in your script. But certainly just running `gnuplot` twice won't magically knit together into a single action!</sub>